# What other structures does a connection on a principal bundle lift?

Tags: differential-geometry, connections, principal-bundles

Let $P(M,G,\pi)$ be a principal bundle. Let $\mathcal{H}\subseteq TP$ (equivalently $\omega:P\rightarrow \Lambda^1_{\mathfrak{g}}T^*P$) be a connection on the principal bundle.

Proposition $1.2$ (page $65$) of Kobayashi and Nomizu says the following:

> Given a connection on $P$ and a vector field $X$ on $M$, here is a unique horizontal lift $X^*$ (a vector field on $P$) of $X$.

Proposition $3.1$ (page $69$) of Kobayashi and Nomizu says the following:

> Let $\tau=x_t, 0\leq t \leq 1$ be a curve of class $C^1$ in $M$. For an arbitrary point $u_0$ of $P$ with $\pi(u_0)=x_0$, there exists a unique lift $\tau^*=u_t$, of $\tau$ that starts from $u_0$.

So, a connection on a principal bundle lifts **vector fields on $M$** uniquely to (horizantal) **vector fields on $P$** and lifts **paths on $M$** uniquely (after fixing initial point) to horizantal **paths on $P$**.

Does connection on $P(M,G)$  lift any other geometric structures on $M$ to structures on $P$?

I am not even sure if this question is well posed. Nevertheless, I will leave it like this, I can take  suggestions to make this better.

Comment: Connection is a tool to identify fibers along smooth paths, whether it is an Ehresmann connection (which is explicitly defied as such) or usual connection, which defines action of vector fields on sections of your bundle and does same thing after integration. Either way, connection does not lift anything per se, but gives you an extension of whatever thing you choose in one fiber to the whole total space — be it a vector in tangent bundle, a point in fiber (as in your examples) or something else.

Comment: Each sentence make sense for me, on the whole I think I don’t understand